# The equivalent code of np.random.rand Python

Tags: python, numpy, programming-languages

What does the function of numpy.random.rand() do? I read the documentation and it says *Create an array of the given shape and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1)*. After reading the documentation, I still don't understand how numpy.random.rand() works.

I would like a better understanding by relating the numpy.random.rand() function to any programming language, it can be C++, Java, etc. A pseudo code explanation of the *numpy.random.rand* still acceptable and helpful to me. Such as the example below:

```
equivalentRandomRandPython(size,size) {
      seed = size*size
      return seed*this.random();
}
```

I know this wrong. Can someone help explain? I would appreciate it.

EDIT: This thread has a few step more to be solved and the hint was given by @Apalala regarding the equivalent of numpy.random.rand function to other code which can be used for any programming languages. The numpy.random.rand has equivanlent to the code which has a *strong random numbers cryptographically*. But the relation between that definition and the seed is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The function is more like the code below.  You do not alter the RNG *seed* with this; I think you've mis-used the term in your example.

```
equivalentRandomRandPython(len, wid) {
    for (row=0; row < len; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < wid; col++) {
            array[row, col] = random()
    return array
```

This assumes that `random` is a canonical RNG the returns a float in the range [0.0, 1.0).
I've left out allocating the array, but you asked more about the random aspect.

Comment: I think the cannocial RNG does not match with how numpy.random.rand random works. Because the cannocial RNG is not a uniform distribution like in the documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html

Comment: As described in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html) the basic random function is uniform.

Comment: Yes it is uniform. But cannocial RNG is not uniform which means a certain range or seed given each time the function run.

Comment: For my terminology, `basic === canonical`.  What are *you* using as "canonical"?

Answer (score 1):

I'll add that seeding from the data would eventually incur in a security risk, as the sequence would be subject to reverse engineering.

Python's and numpy's random number generators work from with the best random seeds the computer can produce.

For reproducibility during testing, the random number generators can be seeded (`seed(n)`, and `n` can be whatever you want to make the sequence reproducible).

Note that for anything involving security, the Python docs recommend using the [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module.

Comment: Now this is make sense! If you kindly give me just one more hint which is related to the seed() function, I will appreciate more :)

Comment: @sementara You can hardcode a seed (it can be `0`) in unit tests. You can hardcode other values to make simulations reproducible. For anything involving security, the Python docs recommend using the `secrets` module.

Comment: Could you please explain by showing the code example? I would be very grateful. Thanks!